# Python daylight savings time localized problem

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

From Python I need to make queries to a database using tuples that contain dates. When the date marks daylight saving time this glitch occurs, i.e. two dates are the same (i.e. ,2021-03-28 01:00:00 and 2021-03-28 01:00:00, instead of 2021-03-28 01:00:00 and 2021-03-28 02:00:00).

[image]

To manage the date I used the following form but without success

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_time_local = timezone('Europe/Rome').localize(date_time, is_dst=True)
```

where for example

```
date_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 2, 0, 0)
print(date_time.isoformat())
2021-01-02T00:00:00
```

and

```
print(date_time_local.isoformat())
2021-01-02T00:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: so what is `date_time`? a datetime object? looks like a pandas DataFrame on the screenshot... btw. you have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in Python 3.9 - [pytz deprecation shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).

Comment: date_time is datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 2, 0, 0) object

Comment: I update my question. Thanks to point out the miss

Comment: on 2021-03-28, there was a DST transition forward (1 am -> 3 am), so if the data represents local time, "2021-03-28 02:00:00" should *not* exist in the input (or one of the "2021-03-28 01:00:00" is superfluous), no?

Comment: I need to download and store hour-by-hour some data in a SQL database. When two date occurances happen the SQL stop to run.

Comment: If using UTC would be an option, you'd avoid any DST issues

Comment: Thanks, do you have some link to study and/or with example? Thanks in advance

Comment: basically you'd use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` to get the machine's current UTC time which you can use as timestamp for your data - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). However since I don't know what exactly you need to do in what context, this is kind of in the guessing range ;-)